# Why running flask application using python instead of Flask-CLI produces ImportError?

Tags: python, flask, flask-cli

When I run my application using `flask-cli`, the app starts normally.

I set `HOST` and `PORT` env variables and run it like:

```
flask run --host ${HOST} --port ${PORT} --no-reload --no-debugger
```

**PROBLEM**:

When I run it like `python3.6 main.py`, I get some import errors (*which I don't get using flask-cli*):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 21, in <module>:
    from runn.models import User, Town
  File "/home/dinko/my-app/runn/models.py", line 9, in <module>
    from main import db
  File "/home/dinko/my-app/runn/main.py", line 21, in <module>
    from runn.models import User, Town
ImportError: cannot import name `User`
```

I know it maybe due to the *circular* imports, but I'm not sure how it works using *flask-cli*. Is there any solution to run it like with *flask-cli*, but using `python3.6 main.py` instead ?

Comment: What are the contents of your `main.py`?

Comment: The way flask loads your app is complex, but seems self-contained in here: https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/master/src/flask/cli.py

Comment: I successfuly run it by using `python -m flask main.py`. I'll add that in answers below. Cli.py is too complex for me to implement it at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a way how to run my flask app by using `python -m flask run`.